# Convert days to hours in HHH:MM:SS Format (Nvarchar)

Tags: sql, sql-server, format, hour

I have a table where i need to convert for example 2.6 days or 5 days, 3.2 days etc to hours. Since it is above 24 hours format i know i need to convert to nvarchar. I searched many forums and i cannot see exactly how can i do specifically this, i think i have to convert this days to seconds and then from seconds to nvarchar format. does anyone have any idea?

Thx all :)

Comment: what datatype do you use to store the number of days, what datatype do you want to save the hours to ? it seems like a simple arithmetic operation as we know 1 day = 24 hours.

Comment: in this case it would be decimal(3,1) and datatype nvarchar for hours because it is above 24 hours and SQL doesn't allow it. i saw something similar in this page but it was ssis       "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/190ae35c-a604-408e-987d-f53a605478e4/convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-using-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices".    but it is assuming it is already in seconds i still have to convert days to seconds unless there is a direct way to convert days to hours in nvarchar

Comment: you do not work with datetimes, you work with numbers. Just store the hours as decimal as well. The conversion between days and hours : hours = days * 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to think you need to use nvarchar. But that is not necessarily the case. If you can store your hours as decimal. The solution is simple

```
hours = days * 24
```

If you want to break it down to hours minutes and seconds you need to convert it to seconds. There are 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute.

```
seconds = days * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Once you have the seconds you can use the division operator (/) togheter with the modulo operator (%). If you store your days as decimal (3,1) you will not have to worry about seconds, because the resolution is too low.

```
select 
 days
 ,CAST(days * 24 * 60 * 60 as int) as totalseconds --days converted to full seconds
 ,CAST(days * 24 * 60 as int) as totalminutes --days converted to full minutes
 ,CAST(days * 24  as int) as totalfullhours --days converted to full hours
 ,CAST(days * 24 * 60 as int) % 60 as remainingminutes -- since the row above contains full hours, we need to find out how many minutes are in the split hours f ex 0.2 hours
 ,CAST(days * 24 * 60 * 60 as int) % 60 as remainingseconds -- this will always be 0 because of your precision
from YourTable
```

If you still want the result as a single string column (HH::mm) it will will be

```
select 
     CAST(CAST(days * 24  as int) as varchar(10)) + ':' + RIGHT('0'+CAST(CAST(days * 24 * 60 as int) % 60 as varchar(10)),2) 
    from YourTable
```

Comment: @rafamaniac . . . I'm surprised you would want results like `23:1` for 23 hours and 1 minute, rather than `23:01`.  Also, this doesn't seem to answer the question you asked, because it doesn't include seconds.

Comment: considering he stores his days as decimal(3,1) mathematics tells us that there will be no seconds -you will have full minutes always. But good catch on the 23:1 vs 23:01. I'll update my answer to cover that.